# How javacards Logs data in the card?

Tags: logging, smartcard, javacard

I want to know how transactions will be logged in a java card? did it performed by applets?
and after transactions, how I can read log events? did the card supplier put a function in the .dll files to read log or something?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a Java Card applet logs events, it does this in exactly the way that it's programmer designed the logging mechanism. Logging/transaction history/etc. is usually something application-specific, thus, there is no standardized logging facilities.